# Simple issue while trying to return random value

Tags: javascript

I'm facing the issue when trying to return random number from the function.
Can anyone explain?

const MyButton = document.querySelector(".Flipper");

```
    MyButton.addEventListener("click", recordLog);

    function recordLog (){

        MyButton.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            
        let RandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

            
        return RandomNumber;

        console.log(RandomNumber);

    };
```

I suppose to get the random number and consol log it

Comment: Your `return` statement exits the function before your `console.log()` so it will not run. Put the `return` at the very very end of the function.

Comment: You return before logging

Comment: May i recommend that you try using an IDE like Intellij Idea or Visual Code Studio? It would provide handy warnings, like the `console.log` statement is unreachable.

Comment: you cannot write code after return statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any statement after return in a function does not get executed because it marks the function as end, you would have to put all the things before return in order to some them, generally return is at the last of the function

Answer (score 0):

console.log won't be printed after return statement. Change the function as follow

```
function recordLog (){

        MyButton.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            
        let RandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

        console.log(RandomNumber);

        return RandomNumber;



    };
```